# React Native : unable to resolve module - Android Emulator

Tags: react-native

Running react native app in android emulator using port 8088 and I see this error.

I have tried running in default port 8081 and the basic app welcome page works ok but the changes are not reflected in the app. My work mcafee uses the same port so I have changed the port in Android emulator to '10.0.2.2:8088' and tried running react-native run-android --port 8088 and I see the error as shown here :

[image: error]

I have tried manually pasting index file to react-native/scripts folder, now I see this :

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using a post in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908. Copied few files to older version and tried to restart the app in port 8088 - worked ok. Can see the changes reflected too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reverse your ports too.

enter this command on the project root

```
$ adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8088 tcp:8088
```

also, check the link below for more info

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Comment: works ok without doing this for me. I am not working on actual device but on emulator.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is already given in the red screen above. They have suggested you to do the following.:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
npm start --reset-cache
rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*
```

Try these commands while you're in root folder of **App.js** and running bash terminal. I had solved my problem just deleting **node_modules** folder and reinstalled node modules by **npm install** and then restart the app. Everything worked out fine!

Comment: Thanks. I have not installed watchman (followed react native cli getting started tutorial!). I have downloaded it now and tried running watchman.exe and it does nothing.
(I have also tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling npm earlier and didnt fix the issue).Could you please check if you can see index.js in .\node_modules\react-native\scripts folder ?

Comment: watchman was optional to see if it can fix. By the way, I had fixed similar issue by deleting the node_modules folder and reinstall the module again then restarting the app solved for me

Comment: ok, but the issue I faced seems to be do with latest react native version. Going back to older version and copying few files fixed the issue and I am now able to run app on port 8088